# How to use ObservableObject with UIViewRepresentable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13, swift5

I'm building a `SwiftUI` app using MVVM.

I need some additional behaviors for text field, so I'm wrapping a `UITextField` in a `UIViewRepresentable` view.

If I use a simple `@State` in the view that contains my text fields to bind the text, the custom text field behave as expected; but since I want to store all texts of my text fields in the view model, I'm using an `@ObservedObject`; when using that, the text field binding doesn't work:
it looks like it's always reset to initial state (empty text) and it doesn't publish any value (and the view doesn't refresh).
**This weird behavior happens only for `UIViewRepresentable` views.**

My main view contains a form and it looks like this:

```swift
struct LoginSceneView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: LoginViewModel = LoginViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(spacing: 22) {
                UIKitTextField(text: $viewModel.email, isFirstResponder: $viewModel.isFirstResponder)
                SecureField("Password", text: $viewModel.password)
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("LOGIN")
                }
                .disabled(!viewModel.isButtonEnabled)       
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 40)
        }
    }

}
```

The view model is this:

```swift
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    @Published var isFirstResponder = false

    var isButtonEnabled: Bool { !email.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty }

}
```

And finally, this is my custom text field:

```swift
struct UIKitTextField: UIViewRepresentable {

    // MARK: - Coordinator

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

        private let textField: UIKitTextField

        fileprivate init(_ textField: UIKitTextField) {
            self.textField = textField

            super.init()
        }

        @objc fileprivate func editingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
            let text = sender.text ?? ""
            textField.text = text
            textField.onEditingChanged(text)
        }

        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            self.textField.onEditingBegin()
        }

        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            self.textField.onEditingEnd()
        }

        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            self.textField.onReturnKeyPressed()
        }

    }

    // MARK: - Properties

    @Binding private var text: String
    private let onEditingChanged: (String) -> Void
    private let onEditingBegin: () -> Void
    private let onEditingEnd: () -> Void
    private let onReturnKeyPressed: () -> Bool

    // MARK: - Initializers

    init(text: Binding<String>,
         onEditingChanged: @escaping (String) -> Void = { _ in },
         onEditingBegin: @escaping  () -> Void = {},
         onEditingEnd: @escaping  () -> Void = {},
         onReturnKeyPressed: @escaping  () -> Bool = { true }) {
        _text = text
        self.onEditingChanged = onEditingChanged
        self.onEditingBegin = onEditingBegin
        self.onEditingEnd = onEditingEnd
        self.onReturnKeyPressed = onReturnKeyPressed
    }

    // MARK: - UIViewRepresentable methods

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator { Coordinator(self) }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        textField.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.editingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that `UIViewRepresentable` is created every time that some binding var is changed. Put debug code to check.

```swift
struct UIKitTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    init() {
         print("UIViewRepresentable init()")
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is indeed; but I think it's supposed to do it, the initializer takes a `Binded<String>` as text, so I guess the problem is that the passed text is not updated and it is always an empty string. If I use a `@State` instead of a `@ObservedObject` everything works as expected.

Comment: I put second `UIKitTextField` your code works

```
                UIKitTextField(text: $viewModel.email)
                UIKitTextField(text: $viewModel.email)

```

Comment: I put the second `UIKitTextField` into
`LoginSceneView` and the second field are updated when I type into the first field

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your code, see if that's what you are looking for.

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var password = ""

    var isButtonEnabled: Bool { !email.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty }

}

struct LoginSceneView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: LoginViewModel = LoginViewModel()

    var body: some View {


        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(spacing: 22) {
                UIKitTextField(text: $viewModel.email)
                SecureField("Password", text: $viewModel.password)
                Button(action: {
                    print("email is \(self.viewModel.email)")
                    print("password is \(self.viewModel.password)")
                    UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
                }) {
                    Text("LOGIN")
                }
                .disabled(!viewModel.isButtonEnabled)
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 40)
        }
    }

}

struct UIKitTextField: UIViewRepresentable {

    // MARK: - Coordinator

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

        let textField: UIKitTextField

        fileprivate init(_ textField: UIKitTextField) {
            self.textField = textField

            super.init()
        }

        @objc fileprivate func editingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
            let text = sender.text ?? ""
            textField.text = text
            textField.onEditingChanged(text)
        }

        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            self.textField.onEditingBegin()
        }

        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            self.textField.onEditingEnd()
        }

        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            self.textField.onReturnKeyPressed()
        }

    }

    // MARK: - Properties

    @Binding private var text: String
    private let onEditingChanged: (String) -> Void
    private let onEditingBegin: () -> Void
    private let onEditingEnd: () -> Void
    private let onReturnKeyPressed: () -> Bool


    // MARK: - Initializers

    init(text: Binding<String>,
         onEditingChanged: @escaping (String) -> Void = { _ in },
         onEditingBegin: @escaping  () -> Void = {},
         onEditingEnd: @escaping  () -> Void = {},
         onReturnKeyPressed: @escaping  () -> Bool = { true }) {
        _text = text
        self.onEditingChanged = onEditingChanged
        self.onEditingBegin = onEditingBegin
        self.onEditingEnd = onEditingEnd
        self.onReturnKeyPressed = onReturnKeyPressed

    }

    // MARK: - UIViewRepresentable methods

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator { Coordinator(self) }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        textField.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.editingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }

}
```

I highly recommend not making your UIViewRepresentable complex for features like using of `isFirstResponder` to do what's possible with alternative ways unless necessary. I'm assuming you want to use that as a parameter to dismiss the keyboard. There are some alternatives like :

```
extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```